# call jboss web service from other machine

Tags: web-services, jboss5.x, soapui

I've created a contract-last web-service which is deployed on a Jboss AS on my VDI machine. I can get the WSDL just fine from localhost, but if I try to call the webservice from my laptop or any other machine I simply cannot connect to it.

I'm using SoapUI to test with and I just get a NullPointerException when I call it and if I try to get the WSDL via a browser it just times out.

I've tried to use a listener to see if I can connect to the VDI from other machines and that works just fint.

Any suggestions what I could try? - I'm thinking that it could be some property setting in some Jboss AS properties file, but the only thing I've found is "jboss.bind.name" which is set to "0.0.0.0" which should allow other machines to connect to the web-service, but no luck :/

Hilfe?

Comment: Do you get the nullpointer in SOAP-UI or in JBoss? If you get this in SOAP-UI you're probably using the correct host. If you get a 404 in SOAP-UI than it's indeed a networking issue.

Comment: I get the NPE in SoapUI.. It seems like it can connect tot he VDI just fine, something is preventing the message to be delivered to JBoss AS..

Comment: You don't seen any logging in JBoss logfiles? Have you checked with wireshark on the VDI to see what is actually being send over the line?

Comment: Hi again.. sry for late reply..

It seems like all I had to do was add the argument "-b 0.0.0.0" when I start the jboss server.. simple solution to a big problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add "-b 0.0.0.0" to my startup script